# Scala looping through an object

Tags: scala

I am getting an object through this line:

```
val product_array:Option[Any] = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(products_json)
```

The object when printed out looks like this:

```
(product1Id,Map(product_picture -> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/73/IPhone_3G.png/250px-IPhone_3G.png, product_price -> 299.99, recipient_picture -> https://www.allianz.com/static-resources/de/presse/mediendatenbank/people/v_1338807733000/zimerer_portrait_small_326x217.jpg, product_amount_gifted -> 100.00, recipient_username -> jDoe, product_name -> iPhone 3G, recipient_id -> 12345))(product2Id,Map(product_picture -> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/7/7c/1stGen-iPad-HomeScreen.jpg/220px-1stGen-iPad-HomeScreen.jpg, product_price -> 399.99, recipient_picture -> https://image1.masterfile.com/em_w/05/11/94/400-05119409w.jpg, product_amount_gifted -> 200.00, recipient_username -> MJohnson, product_name -> iPad, recipient_id -> 67890))
```

how do I loop through the array/object to extract the keys and values?

Update:

When I try to loop through the object it send blank values to key and value, below:

```
for((key, value) <- product_array)     {       

}
```

Here is the original json:

```
{
   "product1Id":{
      "product_name":"iPhone 3G",
      "product_price":"299.99",
      "product_amount_gifted":"100.00",
      "product_picture":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/commons\/thumb\/7\/73\/IPhone_3G.png\/250px-IPhone_3G.png",
      "recipient_picture":"https:\/\/www.allianz.com\/static-resources\/de\/presse\/mediendatenbank\/people\/v_1338807733000\/zimerer_portrait_small_326x217.jpg",
      "recipient_username":"jDoe",
      "recipient_id":"12345"
   },
   "product2Id":{
      "product_name":"iPad",
      "product_price":"399.99",
      "product_amount_gifted":"200.00",
      "product_picture":"https:\/\/upload.wikimedia.org\/wikipedia\/en\/thumb\/7\/7c\/1stGen-iPad-HomeScreen.jpg\/220px-1stGen-iPad-HomeScreen.jpg",
      "recipient_picture":"https:\/\/image1.masterfile.com\/em_w\/05\/11\/94\/400-05119409w.jpg",
      "recipient_username":"MJohnson",
      "recipient_id":"67890"
   }
}
```

Comment: Please share the orignal JSON. The value that you've printed out doesn't look like it matches the type that you've assigned to `product_array`.

Answer (score 5):

First, note that `parseFull` returns `Option`, it means your first step is to check if it contains something or not (parsing error occured for example), I suggest you to use pattern matching for this:

```
products match {
  case Some(p) => println("Products found")
  case None => println("Error parsing JSON")
}
```

If your option contains actual value, it'll be placed in `p` variable. Next, note that parseFull returned `Option[Any]`, so `p` is `Any` too. It should be casted before iterating:

```
p.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]
```

Now you can iterate through the map, let's use `for`:

```
for {
  (id, desc) <- p.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]
  (propName, propValue) <- desc
} println(propName + "=" + propValue)
```

It looks like a single loop, but actually it is a double loop. It iterates through the outer map, and enters each inner map. Inside the loop body you can access `id`, `desc`, `propName` and `propValue` variables. It is probably what you are looking for.

Entire script:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON._

val json = """{"product1Id":{"..."recipient_id":"67890"}}"""

val products = parseFull(json)

products match {
  case Some(p) => 
    for {
      (id, desc) <- p.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]
      (propName, propValue) <- desc
    } println(propName + "=" + propValue)

  case None => println("Error parsing JSON")
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: instead of "println(propName + "=" + propValue)" I am trying to do this: "product_array2(id) ++ Array(propName-> propValue.toString)" but it is not working. I want to create a multidimensional array. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to create an `Array` or a `Map`?

Answer (score 2):

So you have a nested Map.  Try something like this:

```
val your_map = product_array.get().asInstanceOf[Map[String,Map[String,Any]]]
for((key1, value1) <- your_map){
    for((key2, value2) <- value1){
        // now use key2 and value2
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't figure it out, I tried looping through the array but it won't work.

Comment: I think you want to loop through the keys/values of the Map.

Comment: I can't access the map using for((key,value) <- my_map). It gives me empty values.

Comment: It said that product_array .get() doesn't take parameters,.